# Integrating Spring Security with HSQLDB

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, hsqldb

I struggling to connect my HSQLDB and Spring Security configuration. I'm using Spring Data JPA and I already put some data in. 
How do I configure this method

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN");

}
```

to connect with my hsqldb and retrieve usernames, password and roles ?
Here's the [github](https://github.com/Kadyen/AccountMonitor)

---

I figured it out, the code that has to be added is:

```
 @Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .build();
    return db;
}
```

and the connection:

```
 @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select u.username, u.password, 1 from User u where u.username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT u.username, role.name FROM User u JOIN user_roles ON u.id = user_roles.users_Id JOIN Role on user_roles.roles_Id = role.id WHERE u.username = ? ").passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowire
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Implement UserDetailsService class and overide `loadUserByUsername()` method where you will load user authenticationdetails from you database using repository methods(as you are using spring data jpa)

```
@Autowire
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

Comment: I know what site you took it from but I tried to do it this way and still doesn't work

Comment: Could you provided some more configuration code that will be helpful